# Unknown class in flash gomx

Tags: flash

The problem is simples as this, I don't have the slightest what this gomx class is:

```
gomx.Document.setup (maintop.FrasesObj,frases_mc);
```

I have a lot calls like these in the .as files of this site, no import, nothing, I can't find any reference in the code except this line.

Also, I can't seem to find any information on the web about this class..

The only thing that I know is that it takes one object and one movieclip. I don't know if this is in house code or not, I can't find it anywhere on our disks so I think not..

Thanks all for any input you can give me..

Comment: Hmm. Since you have what looks like the whole package in the call you wouldn't find an import statement necessarily. If I had to guess I'd say it's an internal pseudo-framework. Ask the person who provided the files?

Comment: Thanks Myk, the person who has provided the files no longer works here.. so I think I won't be able to do anything about this.. thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is likely a fully qualified reference, meaning gomx is not a class but rather a package. That's why you're not seeing import statements. If you had import statements, the would likely look something like:

```
import gomx;
import maintop;

Document.setup(FrasesObj, frases_mc);
```

So look for a folder called gomx in your source path and you should find the code you're looking for. If not, check your library dependencies, it's likely that the code is in a SWC if not directly in your source path.

Comment: Hi macke.. sorry for the late response, but you were right, after an exaustive search for the the string _gomx_ in one of the server's I found it.. thanks..